# Fall leaves in river rock

Tags: landscaping

Does anyone have an idea on how to keep fall leaves out of river rock landscaping? Tired of cleaning leaves out of landscaping for days. Tried using an old pool cover but didn’t work well. Thanks!

Comment: I see this landscaping on TV shows and always think "What a mess in a couple months with leaves,needles,twigs.acorns,pine cones, seedpod ( such as sweetgums) . I have enough just blowing this stuff off a concrete driveway.

Answer (score -1):

The one and only way other than plucking them off the bank by hand is to blow the leaves off of the banks of rock AWAY from the stream.

I could not live without my gas powered Stihl blower, or my Red Max Line Trimmer!  Gas, not electric.  Power makes one feel IN CHARGE and have a CAN DO attitude!  And more likely to attack a project with joy.  So much fun to see results, immediately.

Blow the leaves off of the rocks, the river rocks, BACK UP ONTO THE BANKS if at all possible.  Clogging up the riparian system is a no no.  Those piles will decompose all by themselves or one could easily bag them up and dump them on their compost pile as 'brown' organic matter to include moisture.

You really really want a gas powered blower!  Amazing how fast many types of projects outside need a gas powered blower. Don't get weak and try to blow the sawdust and crap out of your garage because more than likely you have fire sprinkler systems?  A lesson one does not need to make again!

Make sure you mix the gasoline correctly with oil!  Make sure you use gasoline WITHOUT Ethanol.  Have replacement air and gas filters and replace those guys after just a few major dusty projects.  Keep the dirt out of the machine and that machine will last forever.

Comment: Thank you. My river rock landscaping is around an in ground pool area so no where to blow the leaves. Thank you though for the info.

Comment: Better yet, just don't blow the leaves into the pool.  Easy to rake up and put in the compost.

Comment: You could cover your pool and water feature with landscape fabric or even reemay.  Blow the debris and leaves onto the light fabric, collect and then dump.

Comment: Echo is good but not as good as stihl. How can one clean house without a gas blower ?

Comment: I am loving this!  I have TRIED and will never do that again!  Mostly because of fire sprinklers!  Stihl is my machine!  Major huggs, coder!